# How can I add a link to another website using react-icons in Next.js

Tags: next.js, hyperlink, react-icons

How can I add links to my react-icons. I want to link the LinkedIn button to my linked in and have a mailto option for the mail icon.

I am using Next.js and TailwindCSS to create my application.

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
<div className="text-5xl flex justify-center gap-16 py-3 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
    <AiFillLinkedin href="https://www.google.com/"/>
    <AiFillMail href="mailto:info@mailgo.dev"/>
           
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to wrap this in `a` tag?

```
<div className="text-5xl flex justify-center gap-16 py-3 text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-50">
    <a href="https://www.google.com/"><AiFillLinkedin /></a>
    <a href="mailto:info@mailgo.dev"><AiFillMail /></a>
 </div>
```